# Why is the width: 100% not working for my responsive design?

Tags: html, css

I am creating my portfolio and I stumbled upon an error, which I am not able to resolve for a responsive design.
Using the chrome developer tool, I see that my width: 1000% is struck out when the screen width is less than or equal 1200px;

Look at the image, the red border is just there to make sure that the media query was indeed working, I have stripped a lot of my code for ease, but below are what I think is relative.

header image

[image]

We can see that width is struck out, and I still have the vertical scroll.

**HTML code:**

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <div class="row">
            <img class="logo" src="../img/logo.svg" alt="asheem logo">
            <ul class="main-nav">
                <li><a href="#">Current Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Previous Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact me!</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="hero-text-box">
        <h1>Asheem Chhetri</h1>
        <a class="btn btn-full" href="#">Projects</a>
        <a class="btn btn-ghost" href="#">Show me more</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS code:**

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
html{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #6d6d6d;
    font-family: 'Exo', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
.clearfix{
    zoom: 1;
}
.clearfix:after{
    content: '.';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}
/*------------------------------------------------
Reusable components
------------------------------------------------*/
.row{
    max-width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.box{
    padding: 1%;

}
section{
    padding: 80px 0;
/*    height: 100vh;This solved the page flow problem for now. */
}
/*------------------------------------------------
Header
------------------------------------------------*/
header{
    background-image:  url(../img/imageForMain2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: relative;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
}
h1, h2, h3, h4{
/*    text-align: center;*/
    font-weight: 300;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 2px;

}
h1{
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: white;
    font-size: 200%;
    word-spacing: 4px;
}
.hero-text-box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1140px;
    top: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -20%);
}
```

**Media Query Code:**

```
/*------------------------------------------
Big tablets to 1200px(width smaller than 1140px)
-------------------------------------------*/
@media only screen and (max-width: 1200px){
    .hero-text-box{
        width: auto;
        padding: 0 2%;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .row{
        padding: 0 2%;
    }
}
```

PS: I have this in my head tag already:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

So I clearly do not understand, why I am getting the vertical scroll? and the overflow when the screen size is around 1200px?
Thank you for the help!

Comment: PS: Under media query code it **should be width: 100%** not width: auto. I was just trying width: auto and forgot to change it before submitting the question.

Comment: I can't find a problem with the code you've posted - could you possibly port this over to a CodePen or JSFiddle so I could debug it quickly?

Comment: @JonUleis Here is the Js Fidle, I added the entire CSS there and also the media query is all the way in the end: https://jsfiddle.net/56xnbpsf/

Comment: Thanks - I just checked it out, but I can't reproduce the issue while resizing my browser to any size. The header is staying fully contained. You're seeing a horizontal scrollbar even on this JSFiddle?

Comment: That is strange, how would you suggest to avoid horizontal scroll and the the top header to be visible to screen and not overflow to right side as it is happening for me.

Comment: Is that still happening in your JSFiddle? Is there a chance your browser is zoomed in past 100%? Is the issue happening in other browsers?

Comment: Jon, I am totally surprised. I restarted the browser and now it works. I am clueless now, did not change a single word in code. But I still have a question, when I look at the chrome developer tool, why is the width:100% striked out when screen width is 1200px, for the header div.

Comment: I'm not sure - on the JSFiddle, the `width: 100%` shows up fine, not crossed out, if the browser is 1200px or smaller in width. If you scroll up the styles pane, can you see what width style is overriding it?

Comment: @AsheemChhetri Your `width` is overridden with `media query 1200px`. Even if its not overridden, setting a `width` by `percentage`, requires the parent to have set the `width`. Now, your parent which is `header` does not have any `width` set on it..

Comment: @choz: So the parent header can have its width in px or it should be %. This concept is pretty confusing for me, as when to use %. Any good resource you have in mind that I can read? Thanks!

Comment: @JonUleis: Only one I see is width: 1140px in .hero-text-box. While the percent value is always stricken out for me.

Comment: @AsheemChhetri [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) also explains it really well.. `Percentages - refer to the width of the containing block`.

Comment: May be too late to comment now.. Just trying to find right approach to fix it...
Why cant you make body's overflow-y property in css as hidden? Does it cause any problem for your page some where else?

Answer (score 2):

The main reason why your width is not responsive is because youre using px(pixels), Pixels can be very useful when you're making definite size/width, 
Use, percentage for your width instead of pixel , it will solve your problem.

as for your media query , use percentage too.
set a min-width() for tablets, and different Media query for iphone , nexus and so on. The reasons doing so , because sometimes percentage doesnt solve all the issues.. you might face some layout bug along the way, But to solve that issue when you face that is simple,

When screen size is small, use pixels . Not percentage. but it depends on how you use it . 
Overall, to solve your main issue . Use percentage. I hope it helps :) 
Cheers